# Separate string column into multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

There is this one column that has two variables stored namely date and company name. My goal is to seperate these two variables into two columns.

**date_time/full_company_name**

- 2020-05-19Lopez-Wallace
- 2020-05-12Smith-Simon
- 2020-10-02Jenkins Inc
- 2020-07-06Moore-Weiss

My approach so far was:

```
df['date_time'] = [i[:10] for i in df['date_time/full_company_name']]
df['full_company_name'] = [i[10:] for i in df['date_time/full_company_name']]
df.drop('date_time/full_company_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The code above has worked well, however there are a number of botched data entries in the data set such as:

- 0Lopez, Barton and Jones
- NaNBrown, Singleton and Harrell
- 84635Ball-Thomas

I have thought about some possible solutions such as using a loop with a bunch of if statements to handle the exceptions or perhaps inserting some kind of delimiter into the string and then using `string.split('_')`. But these workarounds are fairly cumbersome.

I can't help but wonder if there is a more generic function or method available out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general iterating over the contents of a pandas series or dataframe is bad for performance and instead vectorized approaches are recommended when possible:

> Iterating through pandas objects is generally slow. In many cases, iterating manually over the rows is not needed and can be avoided...

See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#iteration).

That said, for the "non-botched" entries you can do this:

```py
df['date_time'] = df['date_time/full_company_name'].str.slice(0, 10)
df['full_company_name'] = df['date_time/full_company_name'].str.slice(10, None)
df.drop('date_time/full_company_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

For botched entries, if there is no consistent pattern, it's gonna be hard to come up with a programmatic approach, but something that works for your examples and could be extended with other known entry errors is using [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regular expression:

```py
# The first capture group is either a Y-M-D date, the NaN string or a sequence of digits
# The second one is any string
pattern = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|NaN|0|\d+)(.+)'

df['date_time/full_company_name'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Output:

```sh
            0                             1
0  2020-05-19                 Lopez-Wallace
1  2020-05-12                   Smith-Simon
2  2020-10-02                   Jenkins Inc
3  2020-07-06                   Moore-Weiss
4           0       Lopez, Barton and Jones
5         NaN  Brown, Singleton and Harrell
6       84635                   Ball-Thomas
```